# Why won't my code print the value of a variable to the console?

Tags: javascript

Overall I am trying to make a program that takes in users marks, then spits out the mean and the median. This is for an assignment in my computer science course.

For some reason when I write the line, `console.log(avg);` it displays NaN instead of the value of the avg variable. Am I doing something wrong elsewhere in my code?

Here is the rest of my code:

```
var userMarks = [];
for (var counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
    userMarks.push(prompt("What is your mark?"));
}
console.log(userMarks);


var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < userMarks.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(userMarks[i], 3);
}

var avg = sum / userMarks.length;
console.log(avg);
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(userMarks);`?

Comment: `console.log(sum, userMarks)`

Comment: try `console.log(userMarks[i])` inside your loop, it will show you why you've got NaN. NaN usually comes when you are trying to do calculation and you have a string in the mix

Comment: You are mistaken. The value of `avg` **is** `NaN`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`parseInt()` takes a [radix as a second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and you specified 3 when you probably meant 10.

```
sum += parseInt(userMarks[i], 10);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xo3eojq8/)**

> radix  - An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base
>   in mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string.
>   **Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans.**
>   Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to
>   guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce
>   different results when a radix is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to

```
sum += parseInt(useMarks[i], 10);
```

you can do this

```
sum += +userMarks[i];
```

the '+' symbol before the variable name will attempt to convert to number.